# How to concatenate two tensors with intervals in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I want to concatenate two tensors checkerboard-ly in tensorflow2, like examples showed below:

## example 1:

```
a = [[1,1],[1,1]]
b = [[0,0],[0,0]]

concated_a_and_b = [[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
```

## example 2:

```
a = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
b = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

concated_a_and_b = [[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0]]
```

Is there a decent way in tensorflow2 to concatenate them like this?

A bit of background for this:
I first split a tensor c with a checkerboard mask into two halves a and b. A after some transformation I have to concat them back into oringnal shape and order.

What I mean by checkerboard-ly:
[image: checkerboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1: Generate a matrix with alternated values

You can do this by first concatenating into [1, 0] pairs, and then by applying a final reshape.

## Step 2: Reverse some rows

I split the matrix into two parts, reverse the second part and then rebuild the full matrix by picking alternatively from the first and second part

**Code sample**:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones(shape=(3, 4))
b = tf.zeros(shape=(3, 4))

x = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-1)
y = tf.expand_dims(b, axis=-1)

paired_ones_zeros = tf.concat([x, y], axis=-1)

alternated_values = tf.reshape(paired_ones_zeros, [-1, a.shape[1] + b.shape[1]])

num_samples = alternated_values.shape[0]
middle = math.ceil(num_samples / 2)
is_num_samples_odd = middle * 2 != num_samples

# Gather first part of the matrix, don't do anything to it
first_elements = tf.gather_nd(alternated_values, [[index] for index in range(middle)])
# Gather second part of the matrix and reverse its elements
second_elements = tf.reverse(tf.gather_nd(alternated_values, [[index] for index in range(middle, num_samples)]), axis=[1])

# Pick alternatively between first and second part of the matrix
indices = np.concatenate([[[index], [index + middle]] for index in range(middle)], axis=0)
if is_num_samples_odd:
    indices = indices[:-1]

output = tf.gather_nd(
    tf.concat([first_elements, second_elements], axis=0),
    indices
)
print(output)
```

Comment: It's kinda close but still not checkerboard-ly. The output in your post is [[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.],[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.],[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]] which is different from what I am expecting : [[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.],[0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.],[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]] (noticed row 2 is different).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a decent way as it will affect time and space complexity. But it solves the above problem

```
   def concat(tf1, tf2):
      result = []
      for (index, (tf_item1, tf_item2)) in enumerate(zip(tf1, tf2)):
        item = []
        for (subitem1, subitem2) in zip(tf_item1, tf_item2):
            if index % 2 == 0:
                item.append(subitem1)
                item.append(subitem2)
            else:
                item.append(subitem2)
                item.append(subitem1)
        concated_a_and_b.append(item)
      return concated_a_and_b
```